# "Clean" version for P(A or B or C ...) for non-mutually exclusive events?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

*I would like to make a disclaimer that I am still relatively new to probability, if I have used some incorrect naming convention(s) for probability, I do apologize.*

**The Problem**

Suppose you have b number of non-mutually exclusive events such that $P(A_{1}) = P(A_{2}) = ... = P(A_{b})\text.$

Is there a "simplification" (perhaps this is the wrong word) for

$$P(A_{1}\;or\;A_{2}\;or\;...\;or\;A_{b})?$$

**Previous Research**

I looked online and was unable to find anything helpful or that I could understand, except for the fact that for non-mutually exclusive events A and B,

$$P(A\;or\;B)=P(A)\;+\;P(B)\;-P(A\;and\;B).$$
$$P(A\;and\;B)=P(A)\;*\;P(B|A)$$

**My Personal Attempt**

<strike>I gave many goes at simplifying this, and this was my best attempt yet:</strike>

EDIT: As Henry has pointed out in the comments for this post, I was mistaken in some of my assumptions. Therefore, my attempt was wrong. I have also changed the *Previous Research* section to state correct statements.

Comment: Your question directly analogizes to using [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), where you are working with sets $A,B,C,\cdots$ instead of events $A,B,C$.  Then, by analogy, Inclusion-Exclusion provides the formula for enumerating $(A \cup B \cup C \cup \cdots)$.

Comment: As a specific example, suppose that you have $4$ events : $A,B,C,D.$  Further, let $(E,F)$ denote the intersection of events $E$ and $F$.  Then, $p(A ~\text{or}~ B ~\text{or}~ C ~\text{or}~ D)$ equals $$[p(A) + p(B) + p(C) + p(D)]$$ $$-[p(A,B) + p(A,C) + p(A,D) + p(B,C) + p(B,D) + p(C,D)]$$ $$+ [p(A,B,C) + p(A,B,D) + p(A,C,D) + p(B,C,D)]$$ $$- p(A,B,C,D).$$

Comment: $P(A\;or\;B)=P(A)\;+\;P(B)\;+P(A\;and\;B)$ is wrong.  $P(A\;or\;B)=P(A)\;+\;P(B)\;-P(A\;and\;B)$ is correct.  So too is  $P(A\;or\;B)=P(A\; and\; not\; B)\;+\;P(B\; and\; not\; A)\;+P(A\;and\;B)$

Comment: $P(A_{1}\;or\;A_{2}\;or\;...\;or\;A_{b})$ can be written as $P\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^b A_{i}\right)$ and the word is *union*

Comment: ah inclusion exclusion. nothing clean about it I'm afraid . good luck! if it makes you feel any better lots of mathematicians find it very troublesome and unclean (me included!)